# Liferay 7 - List all blogs in template FreeMarker

Tags: java, liferay, freemarker, liferay-7

I'm using Liferay 7 GA5, and I need to create a template for Web Content to print all blogs, to insert in site footer.

Researching, the neatest solution is this:

```
<#if entries?has_content>
    <#list entries as cur_entry>
        ${cur_entry.getUrlTitle()}<br>
    </#list>
</#if>
```

But the variable **entries** doesn't exist and FreeMarker returns to me error "The following has evaluated to null or missing..."

How I can get all blogs and print their values (image, title, short description, link..) ?

Thank you

Comment: That's not the neatest; `<#list entries! as cur_entry>` doesn't need that `#if`. Of course this doesn't help in the original problem, where `entries` never exist...

Comment: Are there other solutions to print list blogs in Web Content templates ?

Comment: i don't get the point ... you want to display blogs in an web content template   ? how do you save these blogs ? as far as I know , liferay offers  to embed web-content in a web-content through a  webcotent structure  and a corresponding web content  template ? do you want to use this ?

Comment: Do you mean the ADT ? Is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is "Web Content to print all blogs"
When using templates they are inserted in context according to the type of your template. As you are using web content the entries variable will not exist.

The way you can proceed is to manually get your entries using Liferay's services, which are populated (if enabled).

After enabling the service locator, you will be looking for this service:

> https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/javadocs/portal-kernel/com/liferay/blogs/kernel/service/package-summary.html

From there you can use the service to get the entries you need, maybe you need the count which is available or some other criteria. As long you know you need to get the entries as a list you freemarker code should be fine.

Comment: Which is the Liferay's service who get entries, and the method name ? I've enabled serviceLocator. Thank you.

Comment: Perfect, service locator is the hardest part =). Are you familiar with the blog services? The local services should be all you need. I will get you a list later today and update the answer. Just to point you in the direction: get the local services: use the company and the qualifiers you want to get the entries and set the entries variable using freemarker assign.

Comment: Not familiar with blog services, only with article services. Ok I understand. I'm waiting for you, thank you =)

Comment: It works, but is better to use ADT to print blogs because so I have other services as renderResponse, indispensable to get URL of each entry.

Comment: You can get from there. It is just annoying. But any way, I agree. It is better to use ADT, it is simpler and proper. The answer was the fit one for the question you posted. If you are able to use ADT it is perfect. BTW you do not need asset publisher, the blogs portlet support it as well.

Comment: Please, accept the answer to close this question. Welcome to SO btw.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same requirement.

I have achieved it using asset publisher which is The best and easiest way.

1. Drag an Asset Publisher and configure it to show only blogs
2. Create an ADT for blogs
3. Write your code in ADT to show image, title, short description, link..

Comment: Ok thank you, this is one way to get list blogs. I'm finding to get list by use of service directly in Web Content without ADT and asset publisher.